# Closed form for $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k \binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am trying to find a closed form for:
$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k \binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}$

I tried to write it as $(a+b)^n$, but I wasn't able to find anything.
I woudl appreciate it if someone could just explain/show me the solution.

Comment: @AnneBauval Not really, in my case I have $p^{n-k}$ in the case of the link it is about $p^k$

Comment: $p^{n-k}=p^n(1/p)^k.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(x+y)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^ky^{n-k}$$

Differentiating both sides w.r.t x,

$$n(x+y)^{n-1}=\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}x^{k-1}y^{n-k}$$

Substituting $x=-1, y=2$,

$$n=\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k \binom{n}{k}2^{n-k}$$

Comment: Please don't duplicate answers.

Comment: Such minor changes are not sufficient to justify what can still be considered as a duplication. And this is a such a FAQ  that there are certainly other duplicates, closer to what you wrote.

Comment: 1) Only experience of harrassement by moderators. 2) "The answer should be in the best interest of the questioner" does not seem to be the philosophy of this site. They look for what they call quality enforcement.

Comment: @BonBon If you have a better answer, you should post it at the earlier question that this one is a copy of. That way, all of the good answers are in one convenient place, instead of spread out over several identical questions.

Comment: @MikeEarnest This post doesn’t answer that “earloer question”, because the problem is different. It’s $k$ there and $n-k$ here. The best answer to one question is not the best answer to the other.